# Правильная организация паттерна MVC в Spring

Tags: java, spring, mvc, spring-mvc, шаблоны-проектирования

Возник следующий вопрос по поводу паттерна MVC. Пишу учебное приложение. Создал Entity (Question). После этого добавил слои DAO и Service. Прикрутил Spring Security. Все отлично, все работает. Решил дальше расширять приложение. Добавил новое entity(User) и дальше не совсем понятно как правильно все строить согласно этому паттерну. У меня должен быть отдельный интерфейс DAO на каждую Entity? У меня должен быть отдельный интерфейс Service на каждую Entity? Мне на каждый сервис нужно создавать отдельный Bean в контроллере? Или все таки Service должен быть только один и работать со всеми DAO?
Структура проекта ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

upd.
Решил добавить, что по логике entity user и question никак не связаны. Не имеют FK между собой, да и в приложении практически пересекаться не должны.

Comment: репозиторий однозначно да. если пока не понимаете что делать, то создавайте отдельно сервис и контроллер. если это кажется слишком простым, то попробуйте в сервисах сделать супер класс на дженериках с вынесением туда всей общей логики, дабы не дублировать код. для начала хватит))

Comment: @Дмитрий так дело не в просто/сложно. А как выглядит "best practice"? Как принято делать людьми? Существует ли общий подход в этом паттерне для создания этих слоев? За супер класс спасибо сделаю на нем. П.с. чего люди вопрос минуснули? Я че-то тупое спросил?

Comment: вы задаете вопрос, касющийся архитектуры приложения. вы наверное слышали, что существуют такие люди, чья позиция звучит как архитектор. как вы думаете зачем они нужны? и второй вопрос: как вы думаете существовали бы такие люди, если бы для любого приложения было готовое решение в виде "best practice"? ответ вроде как очевиден. именно поэтому такого простого односложного ответа нет. с другой стороны разработчику начального уровня не хватает знаний и опыта, чтобы понять, как разрабатывается архитектура приложения. посему есть простое решение, о котором я написал. сложное придет с опытом

Comment: @Дмитрий спасибо, за ответ. Конечно, не ожидал что везде существует очевидное решение, но думал что конкретно в этом паттерне оно есть, общепринятое и используемое везде.

Comment: простите, в каком в этом паттерне?

Comment: @Дмитрий Model-View-Controller

Comment: паттерн MVC не определяет архитектуру вашего приложения в целом. паттерн MVC  говорит о том, как организовать взаимодействие с вьюхой, где контроллер является реализацией одноименного GRASP паттерна. и это никак не мешает использовать такие архитектурные паттерны как сервис леер или репозиторий или любые другие на ряду с MVC. вы должны понимать, что в архитектурных паттернах в принципе нет консенсуса. их огромное количество и в любом приложении они используются в комплексе. а вот что , где и когда использовать и определяет архитектор))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для каждой сущности стоит написать свой сервис и репозиторий

Comment: Спасибо! Это и интересовало!